# Substrate based parachain light client seems to gets connected but ApiPromise is not returned

Tags: polkadot, parachain, light-client, substrate-connect

I am trying to implement smoldot @substrate-connect light client to my DApp using chain specs of a substrate-based parachain. [Substrate connect extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/substrate-connect-extensi/khccbhhbocaaklceanjginbdheafklai?hl=en-GB) is able to discover the parachain as it shows the current block and keeps on syncing but I do not get apiPromise needed to make rpc request. The bootnodes I am using in my chainspecs is publically accessible as I can make RPC calls using curl but the issue is I cannot get apiPromise as suggested by [substrate_connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@substrate/connect) npm package. Can anybody point me toward possible issues...

```
import chainSpecs from '../parachain.json';
import { ScProvider } from '@polkadot/rpc-provider/substrate-connect';
import { ApiPromise } from '@polkadot/api';
import { WellKnownChain } from '@substrate/connect';

const getPolkadotApi = async () => {
try {
    const relayProvider = new ScProvider(JSON.stringify(relayChainSpecs));
    await relayProvider.connect();

    const stringifyChainSpec = JSON.stringify(chainSpecs);
    const provider = new ScProvider(stringifyChainSpec, relayProvider);

    console.log('waiting for connection');
    await provider.connect();
    console.log('check, provider);
    const _api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });
    console.log(`Connected to ${POLKADOT_RPC_URL},API is ${_api}`);
    return _api;
} catch (err) {
    console.log('this is the error', err);
    return null;
}
};
output:
waiting for connection
polkadot.js:42 checkkk ScProvider {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bootnode needs to listen on secure Websocket to catch with substrate connect:

- Node needs to listen on WS instead of default http `--listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333/ws` (do no use --port in this case)
- Set a proxy with WS upgrade and SSL enabled, pointing a DNS
- Specify the WSS address of the bootnode in chainspecs (example: `"/dns/astar-02.wss-bootnode.astar.network/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWMfHf9G1Mtawz4qySe1EqaBmrieidqn2xnEYckUYkpe52"`)

Answer (score 0):

With your error message is not very clear what is happening.

I have followed this tutorial in the Substrate Docs about [How to Connect to a custom chain specification](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/integrate-a-light-client-node/) and with a similar code as yours works fine.

You can check if there is something wrong with your parachain nodes or the chain spec. To do that, test the connection to a Common Good Parachain [Statemint](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-statemint) with the same code to see if it works.

Just change in your code your parachain.json with the [Statemint spec chain](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paritytech/cumulus/master/parachains/chain-specs/statemint.json) and the relay chain connection to Polkadot:

```
const relayProvider = new ScProvider(WellKnownChain.polkadot);
```

You will see that the connections goes well with that message:

```
[smoldot] Parachain initialization complete for statemint. Name: "Statemint". Genesis hash: 0x68d5…de2f. State root hash: 0xc1ef26b567de07159e4ecd415fbbb0340c56a09c4d72c82516d0f3bc2b782c80. Network identity: 12D3KooWNicu1ZCX6ZNUC96B4TQSiet2NkoQc7SfitxWWE4fQgpK. Relay chain: polkadot (id: 1000)
```

And add this code if you want to subscribe to the new blocks and make sure you are getting the info from the chain:

```
await _api.rpc.chain.subscribeNewHeads((lastHeader: { number: unknown; hash: unknown }) => {
    console.log(`New block #${lastHeader.number} has hash ${lastHeader.hash}`);
  });
```